# ConstraintLayout chains use case

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have read about the *Chains* feature in `ConstraintLayout` and all the examples mention chaining a set of `View`/`ViewGroup` objects as follows:

[image]

I have a set of `View` objects as follows:

[image]

Where, each 'X' image is constrained with the text on the right respectively but each 'X' and the text view to right are not wrapped in any `ViewGroup`. All these items are direct children of `ConstraintLayout`.

What I want is to have a chain of,

{{'X' image, `TextView` to its right},

{'X' image, `TextView` to its right},

{'X' image, `TextView` to its right}}

But I don't want to(or wouldn't prefer to) have the {'X' image, `TextView` to its right} as a `ViewGroup` as I am aiming for a flat hierarchy ultimately as much as possible through the use of `ConstraintLayout`.

What would be the optimum way to design this interface?

Comment: use three separate chains

Comment: What I usually do is chain the `X`s vertically, then I chain each `X` with its respective text horizontally. Finally, I constrain the top and bottom of each text to the top and bottom of their corresponding `X`. This results in a flat hierarchy with no additional `ViewGroup`s. Note: I only chain one of the columns vertically. This way if I change the columns `chain mode`, I only have to change it in one place and the remaining rows just follow it

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_one"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_one"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iv_three" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_one"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_one" />

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_two"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_two"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_one"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_one" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_two"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_two"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_two" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/text_white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="72dp"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView1"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="72dp"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView1" />

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView1"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="72dp"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Output**

[image]